# ATTiny85(Digispark) not connected/recognized

Tags: arduino-ide, usb, digispark

I have 1xDigispark(ATTiny85) from Amazon https://www.amazon.pl/gp/product/B076KS2QDS/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1.

When i connect it into USB port nothing happen i didn't get windows sound alert.
And Arduino IDE not detecting it(Not displayed as a port).
[image: Ports]
I have this link to the drivers in settings and drivers installed.
When I try to upload a code with "COM1" port nothing relly happens.

Regards,
Wiktor Wołos

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong board selected in your IDE

This
[image: three digispark clones]

Is a "Digispark (Default 16.5 mhz)" (sic) not a "Digispark Pro". The latter is based on an ATtiny167 not an ATtiny85.

I have bought the exact same item from the same seller.

Comment: Thanks, but for me i not working... :(

Comment: And I have message sending completed before i see "Plug in device now... (will timeout in 60 seconds)" isn't it weird?

Comment: @asdads this information does not belong in a comment to an answer ... it belongs in the question at the top of this page, so that everyone will see it